# How can I simply request axios.all using loop with array of strings in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, axios, array.prototype.map

Please check my code first.

```js
const arr = ['liver', 'heart', 'brain']

const url1 = `www.hospital.com/diseaseName?liver`
const url2 = `www.hospital.com/diseaseName?heart`
const url3 = `www.hospital.com/diseaseName?brain`

const request1 = axios.get(url1)
const request2 = axios.get(url2)
const request3 = axios.get(url3)

const fetchData = () => {
  axios.all( [request1, request2, request3] )
  .then(axios.spread((...response) => {
  const responseOne = response[0].data
  const responseTwo = response[1].data
  const responseThree = response[2].data
  })
}
```

What I'm trying to do is using the every element of **arr, making each item's url, and request using axios.all**

I think I can simplify the code using loop function such as array.map or other methods. I need some guidance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
const URL = 'www.hospital.com/diseaseName';
const arr = ['liver', 'heart', 'brain'];


const requests = arr.map((a) => {
return axios.get(URL + '?' + a);
});


const fetchData = () => {
  axios.all( requests )
  .then(axios.spread((...response) => {
  const responseOne = response[0].data
  const responseTwo = response[1].data
  const responseThree = response[2].data
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tirth, I almost spend two hours figuring it out.

Comment: No problem @Aden Lee